# List string to binding combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

why the combobox items is null,

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=list}" ......>
```

so

```
public List<string> _list = new List<string>();

        public List<string> list
        {
            get
            {
                return _list;
            }
            set 
            {
                _list = value;
            }
        }
```

and add new item

```
while (combodata.Read())
 {
   list.Add(combodata.GetString(0));
 }
```

I think the need to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `DependencyProperty` but I do not know how this, please help me people!

Comment: Use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`. It has `CollectionChanged` event.

Answer (score 3):

A `List` does not provide notification when items are added / removed. You need to use a collection class that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Try using an `ObservableCollection` instead:

```
public ObservableCollection <string> _list = new ObservableCollection <string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ObservableCollection<> or raise OnPropertyChanged("List") after "while (combodata.Read())
".

Comment: @igni Rover makes some good suggestions. You need to learn a bit more about the basics of C# and WPF.

Comment: protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}